# Arbitrary union of closed sets

Tags: general-topology

I faced a question:

> Show that infinite union of closed sets may not be closed in a topological space.

I have considered the cofinite topology on $\Bbb{N}$ and considered the closed sets $\{2^k\}$, $k=1,2,\dots$

So $\cup\{2^k\}$ is not closed. Is my answer correct?

Comment: There are also easy examples in the usual $\mathbb{R}$ topology, like $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right] = (-1,1)$$

Comment: Another example.  In $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, singletons $\{x\}$ are closed.  Of course $\mathbb Q$ is a countable union of closed sets; however $\mathbb Q$ is not closed.  If we deal with "arbitrary unions" (not necessarily countable unions), then **every** subset of $\mathbb R$ qualifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.
In a cofinite topology , the closed sets are the finite sets ( other than $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{N}$ that is).

So singletons are closed. But union of infinitely many distinct singletons is not closed (unless they form the whole set) which they don’t in this case.